# Advantages of pathwise stochastic integrals over standard Itô integrals

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance, stochastic-integrals

I am currently reading about Föllmer's construction of a stochastic Integral that is defined in a pathwise sense. But I am not sure what exactly the purpose of such a construction is. The main applications seem to be in the area of Finance. But in my studies in that area I have not run into situations where the fact that the Itö integral is defined probabalistic causes any problems.

Could someone maybe provide an intuition as to why such a construction is useful or maybe give an example of when it is?

Comment: Not sure this is the same construction but you can try to look up "applications of rough path theory" to get some ideas.

Comment: @Ian there is a connection between rough paths theory and Föllmer's integral. For the details, see section 5.3 of "A course on Rough Paths" by Friz and Hairer.

Answer (score 2):

Föllmer's pathwise stochastic calculus often shows up in robust finance, as it allows us to replicate many classical results in a model-free manner. In particular, the theory focuses on $C[0,1]$ paths which admit quadratic variation along a refining sequence of partitions.
The advantage of model-free finance lies in mitigating so-called "Knightian risk", which refers to the appearance of unknown unknowns when misspecifying a probability model.

One neat example of its use is shown in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304414994901287) which recovers the Black-Scholes PDE in a pathwise manner. For an exhaustive list of examples, you may see the [list of papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=11721128308372805160&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en) that cite Föllmer's *Calcul d'Itô sans probabilités*.

As an aside, Föllmer's pathwise calculus is far more elementary than semi-martingale calculus, which makes it a good tool for teaching mathematical finance to undergraduate students.

Comment: I love your posts @Jose

Comment: @Snoop the feeling is mutual